# Prove that the division algorithm is unique iff $\delta(a+b)\leq\max\{\delta(a),\delta(b)\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be an Euclidean domain with valuation $\delta$. Then we know that for each $a,b\in R$ with $b\neq0$, there exist $q,r\in R$ such that $a=qb+r$, where either $r=0$ or $\delta(r)<\delta(b)$. Now I need to prove that these elements $q,r$ are unique if and only if $\delta(a+b)\leq\max\{\delta(a),\delta(b)\}$. I can prove the forward direction but failed to prove the other direction. Could someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375071/uniqueness-of-q-and-r-of-division-algorithm-doesnt-hold-in-a-general-euclid?rq=1).

Comment: It doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe in your definition of valuation, $\delta(a)\leq \delta(ab)$ for all $a,b\neq 0$. Suppose this is the case. Let $a=q_1b+r_1$ and $a=q_2b+r_2$. Then $(q_1-q_2)b=r_2-r_1$. Assume $q_1\neq q_2$ and $r_1\neq r_2$.

If $r_1=0$ and $r_2\neq 0$, then $\delta(b)\leq \delta((q_1-q_2)b)=\delta(r_2)<\delta(b)$.

If $r_2=0$ and $r_1\neq 0$, then $\delta(b)\leq  \delta((q_1-q_2)b)=\delta(-r_1)=\delta(r_1)<\delta(b)$.

If $r_1\neq 0$ and $r_2\neq 0$, then $\delta(b)\leq \delta((q_1-q_2)b)=\delta(r_2-r_1)\leq \max\{\delta(r_1),\delta(r_2)\}<\delta(b)$.

All of them are contradictions.

Comment: How did you get that 2nd inequality in the 3rd implication?

Comment: Put in $a=r_1$ and $b=-1$ in $\delta(a)\leq \delta(ab)$.

Comment: And put in $a=-r_1$ and $b=-1$.

Comment: $\delta(r_2-r_1)\leq \max\{\delta(r_2),\delta(-r_1)\}$.